# Website displays fine, but 503 error on page validation

Tags: php, apache, joomla, http-headers

I have a website running on Joomla that displays just fine, but when validated returns a 503 server error.  Since there are so many php files in joomla, plugins, etc., and I don't know which one to fix,  I was wondering if I could just do something in the .htaccess file forcing all 503 errors to report 200 instead.  It probably isn't the best way to do it, but I just have no idea how to fix it otherwise.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you should check the webserver error logs for a 500 error...

Comment: Building on what Jonathan said, HTTP 500 is a general ["the server failed somehow" error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error). Your logs may have more useful details.

Comment: Sorry, guys, I just corrected a mistake I made, its actually a 503 error.  Thanks for being patient.  Joomla is so complicated sometimes, its hard to find the source of the error. Also I checked the log and didn't see anything.

Comment: I see quite a few results for "503 error Joomla" in Google .. what have you tried?

Comment: Ok, I figured out what the problem was.  It was a bug where the site was set to "offline", but it still displayed as though it was online, but sent the server code 503 like it's supposed to when its offline.  I changed it to "online", and the site started functioning as normal.  I don't know why it did that, but anyways, that cleared up the problem.  Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your site in offline mode and log in at the frontend, the site will display as normal, however others trying to access the site ( in this case the w3 - validator?! ) will still get a 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable -response. It is not not possible to validate the website while it is in offline mode (but it is easily forgotten that you logged into the page).

To validate the site during development you can set the site in online mode, and protect it with .htaccess-authentication ( http://www.htaccesstools.com/htaccess-authentication/ ), this will pop up a login-box in the w3 validator.

Comment: Hello jonasfh, I appreciate the answer.  To test it, I tried putting the website 'offline' and then opening in a different browser in private mode, and the site still showed up just fine.  I know I have edited some files, and moved it around many times, so something may have gotten messed up in the process.